# download file with request module and pass result to response in meteor and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router, node-request

I want to download file without saving on disk and pass file content to response. Really I want to get file as stream and then pass it to response and client can download file.
for example with below Pseudo-code (with [iron-router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router), [meteor](http://meteor.com/), [request](https://github.com/request/request)):

```
Router.route('/file/download', function() {
    var res = this.response;
    var query = this.params.query;
    var id = query.id;

    var request = Meteor.npmRequire('request');
    var future = new (Npm.require('fibers/future'))();

    request('http://myFileHosting.com/files/download?id='+ id, function (error, response, fileContent) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            future.return(fileContent);
        }
        else
        {
            future.throw(error);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    var fileContent = future.wait();

    res.end(fileContent);
}, { where: 'server' });
```

How to do this?

**What is the real solution for pass file to response on the fly without download on disk?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
Router.route('/file/download', function() {
    var self = this;
    var res = this.response;
    var query = this.params.query;
    var id = query.id;

    var request = Meteor.npmRequire('request');
    var future = new (Npm.require('fibers/future'))();

    request('http://myFileHosting.com/files/download?id='+ id, function (error, response, fileContent) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            self.response.statusCode = 200;
            self.response.setHeader("Content-Type", response.headers['content-type']);
            self.response.setHeader("Content-disposition", response.headers['content-disposition']);
            self.response.end(fileContent);
            future['return'](true);
        }
        else
        {
            future.throw(error);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    return future.wait();
}, { where: 'server' });
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention, It's work but file content is not ok. (fileContent variable contain other content)
I also add this line to your code to attach file name automatically (you can add this to answer too): self.response.setHeader("Content-disposition", response.headers['content-disposition']);

Comment: Hi~, if your file isn't good checkout this option { url: url, encoding: null} }.